# How can I get item from javascript object using keys?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript file defined in a class inside an express app.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

class Settings {
    static getSettings() {
        const activeEnvironment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
        console.log('active ', activeEnvironment)

        const settings = {
            development: {
                databaseName: 'foods',
            },
            production: {
                databaseName: 'foods',
            },
            test: {
                databaseName: 'testdb'
            }
        };
        settings[activeEnvironment] // returns undefined
        return settings[activeEnvironment];
    }
}

export default Settings;
```

But the problem I have is that `settings[activeEnvironment]` returns `undefined`. I have correctly exported `NODE_ENV` in my start script `set NODE_ENV=production & node --require @babel/register ./bin/www`

Anyone can point me on what I'm doing wrong. I'm a bit new to javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the `console.log()` outputs.

Comment: Also if you're using `dotenv`, put the `NODE_ENV=production` in a `.env` file in the root of your project, not in your start script like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need check the value of `const activeEnvironment = process.env.NODE_ENV;` have one of 3 values
`development, production, test`.

If the value not in this list `settings[activeEnvironment]` will return undefined.

```js
const activeEnvironment = 'test';
        console.log('active ', activeEnvironment)

        const settings = {
            development: {
                databaseName: 'foods',
            },
            production: {
                databaseName: 'foods',
            },
            test: {
                databaseName: 'testdb'
            }
        };
        
console.log(settings[activeEnvironment])
```

Comment: I actually found the problem. I console logged the whole `process.env`. For some reason the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` was `development `. There was an extra space in front of it so I had to trim it.